# Creating number of table cells based on variable

Tags: php

I am trying to display some images and radio buttons in a two-column table format.

It should start a new row after every two images, instead, the row is ended even though the counter is less than 2 ($i == $c)

I am getting:

```
<td align="center" bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
<img src=http://web.com/7534560_2.jpg width='200' height='125' />
<br>Primary Image<input type="radio" name="primary" id="primary"  
value=http://web.com/7534560_2.jpg />
**</td></tr>**
<td align="center" bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
<img src=http://web.com/7534560_3.jpg width='200' height='125' />
<br>Primary Image<input type="radio" name="primary" id="primary"  
value=http://web.com/7534560_3.jpg />
```

Instead of the expected:

```
<td align="center" bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
<img src=http://web.com/7534560_2.jpg width='200' height='125' />
<br>Primary Image<input type="radio" name="primary" id="primary"  
value=http://web.com/7534560_2.jpg />
**</td>**
<td align="center" bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
<img src=http://web.com/7534560_3.jpg width='200' height='125' />
<br>Primary Image<input type="radio" name="primary" id="primary"  
value=http://web.com/7534560_3.jpg />
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
$iq = 2; // first image index offset
$c  = '2'; // number of cells in a row
$i  = 0;  // counter

while ($image_qty + 1 > $iq) {  
    if ($i==0) { 
        echo '<tr>'; 
    } 

    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor=#CCCCCC>';
    $image_url = substr($image_url, 0, -4); 
    $image_url = $image_url . "_$iq" . ".jpg";
    echo "<img src=$image_url width='200' height='125' /><br>";
    echo 'Primary Image<input type="radio" name="primary" id="primary" value=' . $image_url .' />';
    echo '</td>'; 

    $image_url = $image_url_org; // reset image value
    $iq++; // increment image number
    $i++;  // increment cell counter

    if ($i == $c) // if number of cells at 2 end row 
    { 
        echo '</tr>'; 
        $i = 0; 
    } 

    if ($i > 0 ) // if cells remaining less than 2
    {
        echo '</tr>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Change `$c = '2';` to `$c = 2;`

Comment: @mmmshuddup: pointless. PHP converts ints/strings automatically.

Comment: $i++, then $i > 0. Yes, $i will be greater than 0 if it starts at 0 and is then incremented. I think you meant for that last if statement to be outside the while loop.

Comment: @MarcB yes I was just glancing and pointing out quick things I noticed that seemed strange is all.

Comment: Ahhh...missed both. Changed to $c=2 then moved the last if statement outside of the loop and works great! Thanks to all!